# Kotlin - Using apply or also on hashmap doesn't work as expected

Tags: kotlin

Here's a snippet where I'm trying to build some query params for an api call.

The functions below attempt to add an entry into an existing hashmap :

```
// Using Apply to insert another entry : 

fun getParamsUsingApply(): HashMap<String, String> {
    return getBasicParams().apply { KEY to ANOTHER_VALUE }
}


// Using also to insert another entry :  

fun getParamsUsingAlso(): HashMap<String, String> {
    return getBasicParams().also { KEY to ANOTHER_VALUE }
}
```

I find this confusing, I expect my hashmap above to have the new entry in both cases if I call any of the functions.

However that isn't the case.

Any ideas why this doesn't work as I expect?

Comment: Any ideas why you expect this to happen?

Comment: What do you expect would happen from creating a `Pair<key, value>` and just flat out ignoring it?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce well you can answer the question below rather than being salty above

Comment: The answer is already given :p repeating it would be strange

Comment: @EpicPandaForce aha! but you still felt the need to comment in salty fashion

Comment: Yes. Yes I did. You're right. [This is the source code for the `apply {` function. I wouldn't expect it to do things that it doesn't do](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/9ffd0db4a87116a0c825f2f0163b8ad3eb1a922f/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L45-L49). If you press Ctrl+B on `apply` in your IDE, you'll see the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`apply`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) and [`also`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) functions do not update the hashmap; they simply execute the lambda passed to them. In your case, the lambda creates a pair, which is then discarded, because no other operations are performed on it.

If you want to return a map with an added entry, you can do, for example, this:

```
return basicParams + mapOf(KEY to ANOTHER_VALUE)
```

Or if you want to use `apply` (note that this will modify the map returned by `getBasicParams`, while the previous snippet will create a new map):

```
return getBasicParams().apply { this[KEY] = ANOTHER_VALUE }
```

Comment: Ah i see. this explains a lot. And I guess for also I would need to use : it[KEY] = ANOTHER_VALUE  I just thought kotlin would apply this automatically for me

Comment: Will `HashMap<String, String>()apply { this[KEY] = ANOTHER_VALUE }` create anonymous class if given as a parameter to a method, like "double brace" initialization in Java?